# How can I create a KSQL table from a topic using a composite key?

Tags: apache-kafka, ksqldb

Say I have a topic with temperature forecast data, as follows:

```
2018-10-25,Melbourne,21
2018-10-26,Melbourne,17
2018-10-27,Melbourne,21
2018-10-25,Sydney,22
2018-10-26,Sydney,20
2018-10-27,Sydney,23
2018-10-26,Melbourne,18
2018-10-27,Melbourne,22
2018-10-26,Sydney,21
2018-10-27,Sydney,24
```

Each entry contains a date, a city, and a forecast temperature, and represents an *update* to the forecast for that city on that date. I can describe it as a KSQL stream like this:

```
CREATE STREAM forecasts_csv ( \
  date VARCHAR, \
  city VARCHAR, \
  temperature INTEGER \
) WITH (kafka_topic='forecasts-csv', value_format='DELIMITED');
```

Now, I want a table that represents the *current* (i.e. the latest) forecast temperature for each city, as well as the min and max of that forecast over time. An example desired output is:

```
{ date='2018-10-27', city='Melbourne', latest=22, min=21, max=22 }
```

How can I achieve this?

I've managed to get the aggregates (min/max) as follows:

```
CREATE STREAM forecasts_keyed \
WITH (partitions=4, value_format='JSON') \
AS SELECT date + '/' + city AS forecast_key, * \
FROM forecasts_csv \
PARTITION BY forecast_key;

CREATE TABLE forecasts_minmax \
WITH (partitions=4, value_format='JSON') \
AS SELECT forecast_key, date, city, \
          min(temperature) as min, max(temperature) as max \
FROM forecasts_keyed \
GROUP by forecast_key, date, city;
```

which gives me output messages like:

```
{"FORECAST_KEY":"2018-10-27/Melbourne","DATE":"2018-10-27","CITY":"Melbourne","MIN":21,"MAX":22}
```

but I can't work out how to combine this with the "latest" reading.

Answer (score 3):

You need to implement a UDAF, let's call it `LATEST`, that keeps the latest value of a given column and key. This is very trivial and you can find out how to add your custom UDAF in the KSQL docs: https://docs.confluent.io/current/ksql/docs/developer-guide/udf.html#udafs

Assuming that you have the `LATEST` UDAF available you can write the following query:

```sql
CREATE TABLE foo AS
SELECT
  date,
  city,
  MIN(temperature) AS minValue,
  MAX(temperature) AS maxValue,
  LATEST(temperature) AS latestValue
FROM forecasts_csv
GROUP BY date, city;
```

Comment: this only works if you created proper keys first, which is what the question is about. You cant group by 2 columns if they are not keys.